# Is color box clashing with jcrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, colorbox, jcrop

I have created an image uploader for my website and have the image popup using colorbox with a crop button so that the person can crop there image and once they press the crop button it saves. but I'm having a fewissues at the moment.

1. In IE when the popup box comes up you first have to click the crop button a few times depending on which IE I am using IE 10 but I have tested IE 8 and you only need to once and it allows you to crop. Once that happens it saves the cropped image in to a folder but does not show the cropped image in the colorbox part of it.
2. In firefox the the crop cursor shows first time the popup box opens but does not save the cropped image to the folder.

here is my code as follows:

this is when the colorbox get used and pops up after the image has been loaded.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'fileSizeLimit': '1.5MB',
                'swf': '/JavaScript/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader': '/JavaScript/uploadify/ImgHandler.ashx',
                'onUploadComplete': function (file) {
                    $.colorbox({ iframe:true, href: "/Mapping/BrochureImgUploader.aspx?file=" + file.name, width: "95%", height: "95%" });
                }
            });
        });


    </script>
```

then on a new new page this is where jcrop comes into play:

```
%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" Theme="" CodeFile="BrochureImgUploader.aspx.vb" Inherits="Mapping_BrochureImgUploader" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Upload Photo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../JavaScript/jcrop/jquery.Jcrop.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JavaScript/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference  Path="~/JavaScript/jcrop/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"/>
    </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfmeh" />
           <img src='' style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" id="upcrop" />
            <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
            <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
            <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
            <input type="button" value="Crop Image" onclick="crop()"/>
 </form>
</body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var is_msie = /msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
        var jcrop_obj;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#upcrop").prop("src", $("#<%=hfmeh.ClientID%>").val())
  $("#upcrop").Jcrop({
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    onSelect: updateCoords
                });
        });

        function updateCoords(c) {
            $('#x').val(c.x);
            $('#y').val(c.y);
            $('#w').val(c.w);
            $('#h').val(c.h);
        };

        function crop() {
            if (parseInt($('#w').val()) > 0) {
                PageMethods.CropImg($("#<%=hfmeh.ClientID%>").val(), $('#x').val(), $('#y').val(), $('#w').val(), $('#h').val(), onCrop)
            }
            else {
                alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
            }
        };

        function onCrop(result) {
            $("#upcrop").prop("src", result);
        }

    </script>
</html>
```

in the server side section of the cropping bit the code it here:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.IO
Imports SD = System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Partial Class Mapping_BrochureImgUploader
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  hfmeh.Value = "/Images/Brochure/uploads/" & Request.QueryString("file")
End Sub


    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function CropImg(img As String, x As Double, y As Double, w As Double, h As Double) As String
        Dim CropImage As Byte() = Crop(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(img), CInt(x), CInt(y), CInt(w), CInt(h))
        Dim SaveTo As String

        Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length)
            ms.Write(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length)
            Using CroppedImage As SD.Image = SD.Image.FromStream(ms, True)
                Dim pos As UInt16 = img.LastIndexOf(".")
                SaveTo = Left(img, pos) & "_crop" & Right(img, img.Length - pos)
                CroppedImage.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(SaveTo), CroppedImage.RawFormat)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return SaveTo
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Crop(img As String, x As UInt16, y As UInt16, w As UInt16, h As UInt16) As Byte()
        Try
            Using OriginalImage As SD.Image = SD.Image.FromFile(img)
                Using bmp As SD.Bitmap = New SD.Bitmap(w, h)
                    bmp.SetResolution(OriginalImage.HorizontalResolution, OriginalImage.VerticalResolution)
                    Using Graphic As SD.Graphics = SD.Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
                        Graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
                        Graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                        Graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
                        Graphic.DrawImage(OriginalImage, New SD.Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), x, y, w, h, SD.GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
                        Dim MS As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                        bmp.Save(MS, OriginalImage.RawFormat)
                        Return MS.GetBuffer()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch Ex As Exception
            Throw (Ex)
        End Try
    End Function
```

I am so good with php and managed to find vb.net tut for me to use. In the server section it saves the cropped image to the folder with the word crop at the end so as not to overite the original image but as I said FF does not save the cropped one at all and IE does not seem to be able to crop from the start without pushing the crop button first.

strangely enough chrome seems to work fine though for both cropping and saving the cropped images.

Is it because the two don't want to work together or have I done something wrong somewhere else?

any help would be great.

UPDATE: I got FF to work now by changing the type=submit to button and it works but am still having issues with IE so i have edit the code to reflect the FF fixbut

Comment: Did you try waiting for the image to load, with a .load event, and applying jcrop only after the image has finished loading?

Comment: the image does finish loading as it shows up in the colorbox window.

Comment: ok so I didn't manage to solve it so instead found something else that seemed to have worked. I used http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/ instead